# Retrieving a particular string from a sentence using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, data-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve a particular string with the Regex Expression from a sentence.
This is my initial Regex:

```
   Regex Reg = new Regex(@"^[KB|kb](\w+)[-]?(\w+)$");

  From input of :
  word word word (KB92922-WMP9) word.
  word word word (KB929222910) word word.
  word word kb28928282 word word.
```

It should be able to retrieve:

```
  KB92922-WMP9
  KB929222910
  kb28928282
```

Treat them as sentences, and we retrieve data by passing a sentence one at a time. Retrieving its data Without the parentheses.

How is this going to work? I have no idea. I think I've got the Regex Expression right but I'm not so sure how to retrieve the data.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# -" and such. THat's what the tags are for.

Comment: I find this very helpful when testing regexes:http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx), (assuming that one sentence might contain both KB12345 and KB98765). it is similar to [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx), but will give you all matching substrings.

If you have the entire text as one string, it's probably not necessary to split it into sentences. Just getting all matches in the entire string will get you the same result as collecting all matches in all sentences within the same string.

Edit: updating the regex you are using

```
Regex Reg = new Regex(@"(KB\d+(?:-[\w\d]+)?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```